# Intro to Javascript class, date not formatting correctly as shown in textbook

Tags: javascript, date

I was hoping someone can provide me with some insight on how to fix an issue that I am having. I have search the forums and google and actually came across someone posting this same question (different activity from the same textbook) back in September but he had no one to give them a solution. The issue I am having with my code is that according to the textbook after I enter it as instructed in the book, it is supposed to be in the format of a dynamic display of: "Today is Wednesday, May 6, 2015. Only 50 days until Frank's Fix-it Memorial Day Sale." However, it comes across as: "Today is ‎5‎/‎6‎/‎2015‎ 2015. Only 50 days until Frank's Fix-it Memorial Day Sale."

As you can see the year is repeated twice and the date not on the full format.

My code is:

```js
function scrollColor() {
  styleObject = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style
  styleObject.scrollbarFaceColor = "#191a1f"
  styleObject.scrollbarTrackColor = "#e4e5e8"
}

function countDown() {
  var today = new Date()
  var dayofweek = today.toLocaleString()
  dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
  weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
  newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
  dateLocate = newDay.indexOf(",")
  monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate + 1)
  yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2015")
  year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)


  var memDay = new Date("May 26, 2015")
  var daysToGo = memDay.getTime() - today.getTime()
  var daysTomemDay = Math.ceil(daysToGo / (1000 * 60 * 24 * 24))

  displayCountDown.innerHTML = "<h3>Today is " + weekDay + " " + monthDate + " " + year + ". Only " + daysTomemDay + " days until Frank's Fix-it Memorial Day Sale.</h3>"
}

function copyRight() {
  var lastModDate = document.lastModified
  var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0, 10)
  displayCopyRight.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:8pt;'>The URL of this document is " + document.URL + "<br />Copyright Frank's Fix-t Hardware. This document was last modified " + lastModDate + ".</p>"
}
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.cell-width {
  width: 50%;
}
table.width {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.left-align {
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.right-align {
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.header1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5f6065;
}
.r_saletext {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  text-align: right;
}
.l_saletext {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  text-align: left;
}
#alignright {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body onload="scrollColor(); countDown(); copyRight()">

  <div class="center">
    <p>
      <img src="make9-1banner.jpg" width="700" height="120" alt="Frank's Fix-it banner">
    </p>
    <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;">Frank's Fix-it Hardware</p>
    <img src="img-metaldivider.jpg" width="700" height="5" alt="divider">

    <div id="displayCountDown" class="center">
    </div>

    <img src="img-metaldivider.jpg" width="700" height="5" alt="divider">
  </div>
  <table class="width">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="header1" style="font-weight:bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12pt">Frank's Fix-it Hardware</p>
        <p>Frank's Fix-it Hardware has been a member of the greater Anaheim and Fullerton community for over fifty years, with four stores. Our Anaheim store, near Disneyland, is open from 6 a.m. to midnight. Monday through Saturday, and 9 a.m. to 9 p.m.
          on Sunday for those emergency repairs that materialize when you least expect them. Our other locations are open seven days a week from 8 a.m. to 9 p.m.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="header1" style="font-weight:bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12pt">Fix-it Membership Club</p>
        <p>Become a member of our Fix-it Membership Club. Every $250 in purchases earns you $10 in Fix-it bucks, which can be applied to any item, including closeout and sale items. Sorry, the only exception is special orders, due to manufacturers limitations.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="center"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;">This week's specials</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="r_saletext">Screw Driver Set 25% Off</td>
      <td class="l_saletext">Free Drill Bit Sharpening</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="alignright">
        <img src="make9-1toolset1.jpg" alt="screw driver set" width="270" height="258">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="make9-1drillbits.jpg" width="272" height="256" alt="drill bits">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="displayCopyRight">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+format+date

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print out your `dayofweek` variable, it will show you that it is something similar to `6/5/2015 15.26.53` and not a textual representation, as you expect.

To solve this, you should have a look at formatting dates in javascript. There should be plenty of questions regarding this on Stack Overflow, and even more on Google!

Answer (score 0):

The `toLocaleString()` function takes two optional parameters, a locale and a format.  Since you're not supplying either, you get output like 5‎/‎6‎/‎2015.  If you set up options for the locale and especially formatting options, you can control what the results look like.  Consult the [MDN page for toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) for a very complete explanation of the function, but expect to spend a few minutes reading.

I'm tempted to post the exact solution you're looking for, but since this is a homework assignment, I'd rather you read up on it and learn how it works for yourself.  If you make progress but get stuck, come back and clarify your question.  if you get **really** close somebody might give you the nudge you need to finish up.

Comment: Note that MDN is documentation for Mozilla JavaScript, it does not necessarily apply to other implementations of ECMAScript. In particular, *toLocaleString* is not required by ECMAScript 2015 to support any additional parameters, that is only available where the [*ECMAScript Internationalization API (ECMA-402)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-8) is supported.